# CodeIgniter how to add link to static file

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, static

I have a problem with static file in CodeIgniter.. I try everything for add some css and js file but it's always a 404 error. I have followed some ask here and other place but nothing.

In particular i have followed this answer: [How to access static assets in CodeIgniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050332/how-to-access-static-assets-in-codeigniter)

Here is where i link css and js file:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/static/css/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/bootstrap/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
```

And my directory is this:

```
/applications
/system
/assets
  - bootstrap
  - static
```

Comment: What's the URL that's giving you the 404?

Comment: Is your `$config['base_url']` setting correct in config.php?

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://ciskeleton.com/'; where ciskeleton.com is name of my local server put also in /etc/hosts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

If it doesn't work, check in your config file (`config/config.php`) if the variable `$config['base_url']` is correct.

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://ciskeleton.com/'; where ciskeleton.com is name of my local server put also in /etc/hosts