# CodeIgniter serves static files as index.php

Tags: php, docker, codeigniter

I'm running an existing php application with `php -S 0.0.0.0:80` in a docker container for debug purposes. It uses CodeIgniter. The link I'm going to is `http://localhost/index.php` and all the other assets are loaded with it as base url. For example, `http://localhost/assets/js/third-party-libraries/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js`.
But each file which comes back to the browser contains the same content as `index.php`.

What am I missing in how CodeIgniter handles queries?

PHP 7, CodeIgniter 3.1.9

Comment: I do not know codeigniter, but I can try to advice. You are getting the same file because .htaccess (or other web server config) forces you to use index.php as an entry point. Normally, there should be some kind of controller or router inside the appliction. So your assets URL is actually a parameter to index.php. So either you create a new controller to serve assets, change routes...

Comment: Or you try to google (have you tried?). For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820314/codeigniter-assets-folder-best-practice  or  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050332/how-to-access-static-assets-in-codeigniter Lots of questions about your problem even on this site.

Comment: As @Anton said, you are likely missing the lines in the `.htacess` that tells Apache to not redirect to `index.php` if the requests points towards a file and/or directory. These would be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` for files and directories respectively.

Comment: The question mentions the use of `PHP -S` server, not Apache.

Answer (score 0):

PHP built-in web server doesn't use an .htaccess to know how to redirect files. But it has a simple rule which needs to be implemented. The `index.php` can return `false` and this means the web server will return the resource as is. From its [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php):

```
<?php
// router.php
if (preg_match('/\.(?:png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    return false;    // serve the requested resource as-is.
} else { 
    echo "<p>Welcome to PHP</p>";
}
?>
```

In the above example requests for images will display them, but requests for HTML files will display "Welcome to PHP".